# Parent child join sql query needed for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table called `PostDkServicePoint` that stores a bunch of longitude / latitude locations. I am calling it like this today - where it will find the top 30 closest locations to the point lat/lng parameters specified.

```
SELECT TOP (30) 
    PostDkServicePoint.location.Lat AS latitude,    
    PostDkServicePoint.location.Long AS longitude,  
    PostDkServicePoint.servicePointId
FROM         
    PostDkServicePoint 
WHERE     
    (PostDkServicePoint.location.STDistance('POINT(40.587990    -73.662457)') IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY 
    PostDkServicePoint.location.STDistance('POINT(40.587990 -73.662457)')
```

Now I have another table called `PostDkOpeningHour`:

```
 openingHoursId int
 servicePointId int
 day varchar
 from1 varchar
 to1 varchar
```

Example rows:

```
 1233   5725    MONDAY      07:00   19:00
 1234   5725    TUESDAY     07:00   19:00
 1235   5725    WEDNESDAY   07:00   19:00
 1236   5725    THURSDAY    07:00   19:00
```

It contains 24000 rows in total.I want join the two tables so that for each of the 30 rows returned from the above postdkservicepoint SQL query it will also show all of the matching child rows in the PostDkOpeningHour table (where servicepointid is the matching key between the two tables).

With such a "join" query - will the latitude/longitude data then just be duplicated for each row with opening hour data like this:

```
5725 40.587990 -73.662457 MONDAY   07:00 19:00
5725 40.587121 -73.662412 TUESDAY  07:00 19:00
```

or is there a way to return it in a more of a parent child relationship style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my humble opinion, you should first get the 30 records and then JOIN with the `PostDkServicePoint` to get the related rows.

```
WITH CTE (latitude, longitude, servicePointId) AS
(
SELECT TOP (30) 
    PostDkServicePoint.location.Lat AS latitude,    
    PostDkServicePoint.location.Long AS longitude,  
    PostDkServicePoint.servicePointId
FROM         
    PostDkServicePoint
WHERE     
    (PostDkServicePoint.location.STDistance('POINT(40.587990    -73.662457)') IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY 
    PostDkServicePoint.location.STDistance('POINT(40.587990 -73.662457)')
)
SELECT
    cte.servicePointId,
    cte.latitude,
    cte.longitude,
    PostDkOpeningHour.day,
    PostDkOpeningHour.from1,
    PostDkOpeningHour.to1
FROM
    cte 
    INNER JOIN PostDkOpeningHour
        ON cte.servicePointId = PostDkOpeningHour.servicePointId;
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I do get an error at this line when I run your code:
      cte.servicePointId
       Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
      Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: Can you post some data results from the first query? Just to build a test environment.

Comment: Ok, there was a missing ','  Please check it here, http://rextester.com/VQH68668  I've simulated with a top(10)

Comment: Thanks for your working example - that is just what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply executing a query along the lines of:

```
select a.Col1
      ,a.Col2
      ,b.Col1
      ,b.Col2
from TableA a
    inner join TableB b
        on(a.ID = b.FKID)
```

where there are 5 rows in TableA and 5000 matching rows per ID in TableB, then yes, your output will have the matching data from both tables for each row returned, resulting in each TableA row being duplicated 5000 times.

This is simply how SQL works and there is no way to return your data otherwise, unless you are returning multiple datasets and joining them together at a later date in your application.  Typically, the network transfer gains in doing this are far outweighed by the processing time to join the data back together in your application, as SQL is incredibly efficient at data manipulation.

If your network traffic is at a premium and you absolutely need every row value - ie: you aren't aggregating the data returned - then you may want to explore joining in application, though it is generally not advised.

Comment: @mcNets  So is your question here whether the `TOP 30` will affect only the first table or the whole final dataset?

Comment: I meant how it would affect performance on the whole final dataset returned - when there are duplicates..

Comment: Yes mcNets - that's what I am aiming for.